# Can Apple.SE be added to the list of sites when voting to close a question as off-topic?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, off-topic

Often when I vote to close a question, I'd like to suggest it belongs on Ask Different. Is there a reason it's not included in the list?

Comment: flag it for a moderator to move. SO mods will move it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally I'd ask for a list of example questions that would benefit from community-driven migrations since the list is chosen based on the frequency and accurancy of migrations. However, Apple.SE isn't anywhere near the most common destinations for questions posted to Stack Overflow.

If you think a question should be migrated to Ask Different, for now please flag it for moderator attention and explain your reasoning.

Comment: Ok, I'll flag for moderation.